# Regex to group numbers in threes excluding decimals

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I define a regex that groups a number into threes excluding decimals?

**Example**

`1123456789` -> ["1","123","456","789"]

`1123456789.999` -> ["1","123","456","789"]

I've tried this Regex:

```
/\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})*$)/g
```

But it outputs the following:

`1123456789` -> ["1","123","456","789"]

`1123456789.999` -> ["999"]

**Edit**: removed `_` from the example strings.

Comment: @DarkBee they tried `/\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})*$)/g`

Comment: Would the 1 to 3 digits always be separated by underscore or dot?  If so, then why can't you just split on those delimiters?

Comment: Can you include a sample with 4 or more digits in a row?

Comment: It is impossible that this regex returns those results. It only reads numbers, not _ so the first one is actually only returning 789, not what you are saying.

Comment: My bad for including `_` in the strings. The strings do not have any separators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [supported in your environment](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind), you can make use of an infinite quantifier in a lookbehind assertion:

```
\d{1,3}(?<!\.\d*)(?=(?:\d{3})*\b)
```

The pattern in parts matches:

- `\d{1,3}` Match 1-3 digits
- `(?<!\.\d*)` Negative lookbehind to assert that the current match is not preceded by a dot and optional digits
- `(?=(?:\d{3})*\b)` Positive lookahead, assert optional repetitions of 3 digits followed by a word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hrPknl/1)

```js
const regex = /\d{1,3}(?<!\.\d*)(?=(?:\d{3})*\b)/g;
[
  "1123456789",
  "1123456789.999"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(s.match(regex))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Update to handle updated question

You could use any [script that adds thousand separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-format-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators), here I assume the number is smaller than MAXINT

```js
const en_formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 });
let value = 1123456789.999;
let formatted = en_formatter.format(value);
console.log(formatted.split(','))

let formatted1 = parseInt(value).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",").split(',');
console.log(formatted1)
```

---

Answers based on original question which was about `1_123_456_789`

Just add the underscore to the regex (assuming there will always be an underscore) and use a negative lookbehind for the decimals
We then map to get the second part of the match, which is the group

```js
const str = '1_123_456_789.999';
const regex = /(?<!\.\d{0,3})(\d{1,3})_?/g;
const matches = [...str.matchAll(regex)];
const digitGroups = matches.map(match => match[1]); // Extracting the first captured group from each match
console.log(digitGroups);
```

Alternative

```js
const groups = '1_123_456_789.999'.split('_').map(str => parseInt(str));
console.log(groups);
```

Comment: Nice answer! My guess is that the underscores are not really in the number... As their regex does not fit with the results annonced. I think we do not have the real case here...

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] of your regex? It looks like their regex but I am not sure it gives the expected result

Comment: @mplungjan your right my regex was almost identical to yours, I am curious as to why you use \d+ in the lookbehind as opposed to just \d and is there a need to add the search for _? at the end. Also your current first regex outputs 999 at the end which should be skipped as per question right ?

Comment: I rolled back to a working version

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But like Salketer mentioned, I mistakenly included `_`s in the example strings. The strings do not have any separators

Comment: Again, thanks for the updated answer.  I'm currently doing `str.split(".")[0].match(/\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})*$)/g)`. But I was looking for a way to only use Regex without any other computation such as `split()`, etc.

Comment: Why? Do you need to do a lot of them?

Comment: I'm not sure of the time complexity of 1) split + regex or 2) just regex. But I thought the split probably doesn't help. Also, just personal inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the regex is set to find the end of the string, marked with the $. That is why it will return the numbers after the decimal only. If you want the oposite, make it start on the start of the string instead.

```
/^\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})*)/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something like this -

```js
const str = '1_123_456_789.999';
const regex = /(?<![\.\d])\d{1,3}/gm;
const matches = [...str.matchAll(regex)];
const digitGroups = matches.map(match => match[0]);
console.log(digitGroups);
```

to get your matches. It adds a digit search to the negative look-behind to get around matching digit strings that may occur AFTER the decimal

Comment: @mplungjan I fixed the nested arrays, also the regex is slightly different from your original answer (even apart from the multiline tag which does not affect output) as this does not output the 999 at the end of the match

Comment: I rolled back to a working version